# Robot framework No Keyword Suggestions

Tags: robotframework

Could anyone help me out -
there are no keyword suggestions appeared on robot project as you can see from attached images.
How can I solve it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: As for your last screenshot, `pybot` is no longer in existence use `robot` since you are on latest 4.0 release.